# What is the perplexity of a mini-language of numbers [0-9] where 0 has prob 10 times the other numbers?

Tags: natural-language, entropy

I'm reading *Speech and Language Processing, Jurafsky and Martin*, in particular chapter 4 where they introduce perplexity see https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/4.pdf (page 8-9)

Here a brief excerpt:

> There is another way to think about perplexity: as the weighted
>   average branching factor of a language. The branching factor of a
>   language is the number of possible next words that can follow any
>   word. Consider the task of recognizing the digits in English (zero,
>   one, two,..., nine), given that each of the 10 digits occur with equal
>   probability $P = 1/10$ . The perplexity of this mini-language is in
>   fact 10. To see that, imagine a string of digits of length N. By
>   Equation (4.17), the perplexity will be:
>
> $PP(W) = ({\frac{1}{10}}^{N})^{-{\frac {1}{N}}} = ({\frac{1}{10}})^{-1} = 10$
>
> But now suppose that the number zero is really frequent and occurs 10
>   times more often than other numbers. Now we should expect the
>   perplexity to be lower, since most of the time the next number will be
>   zero. Thus although the branching factor is still 10, the perplexity
>   or weighted branching factor is smaller. We leave this calculation as
>   an exercise to the reader.

Now this should be fairly simple, I did the calculation but instead of lower perplexity instead I get a higher one.

My calculations were:

Probability of number zero is 10 times the other probabilities.

$P(0) = 10 * P(n =\{1,2,..,9\})$

The sum of the probabilities of all numbers have to add up to 1

$10 * P(n =\{1,2,..,9\}) + 9 * P(n =\{1,2,..,9\}) = 1$

Which implies:

$P(n =\{1,2,..,9\}) = {\frac {1}{19}} $

$P(0) = {\frac {10}{19}}$

So plugging it into the perplexity formula  $PP(W) = P(w_1,w_2,..,w_N)^{-{\frac{1}{N}}}$  the numbers I get:

$PP(0,1,..,9) = ({\frac {10}{19}} * {\frac {1}{19}}^9)^{-{\frac{1}{10}}}  =  15.09224$

which is more that the perplexity calculated earlier where all numbers had equal ${\frac{1}{10}}$ probability.

The book anticipates a lower perplexity instead, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Re the last equation: Is that *really* what your book's formula says?  I suspect you might have misread it.

Comment: I have edited the question and linked to the book, as far as I can tell I'm reporting the formula correctly but again the calculation result is not the one expected so I might as well have got it wrong, I cannot work out what is wrong.

Comment: That is indeed a limited formula.  Use (4.39) instead.  Alternatively, as an approximation, construct a long random sequence of independent occurrences of these ten digits and compute its perplexity.

Comment: @whuber isn't the formula at (4.39) about discounting, I don't think it is about perplexity. I'm not sure how constructing a long random sequence of independent occurrences will help me understand if I got the correct understanding of the formula to calculate the perplexity.

Comment: I believe all of section 4.6 is devoted to explaining this connection.

Comment: This is another reason why I hate perplexity.  If you had been calculating entropy, you would not have made this mistake since the exponents become a simple weighted average of suprisals.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why you get the wrong answer is because the way the calculation has been described in the book is a little confusing. The book says "imagine a string of digits of length $N$". This means a *long* string of digits, not just a string of $10$ digits.

Imagine a *long* string of digits from the new language. On average, in $19$ digits from this sequence, you have $10$ zeros and $1$ of each of the other numbers, because $0$ occurs ten times as often as each of the other digits. Imagine dividing your long sequence into blocks of length $19$. Say there are $M$ of these blocks. Then the perplexity is

$$\left(\left(\frac{10}{19}\right)^{10M}\left(\frac{1}{19}\right)^{9M}\right)^{-1/19M}$$

and just  like in the example in the book, the $M$'s cancel, so the perplexity is:

$$\left(\left(\frac{10}{19}\right)^{10}\left(\frac{1}{19}\right)^{9}\right)^{-1/19}$$

Comment: If we observe a number sequence where each number occurs equal times then the perplexity will be 15, I guess mentioning perplexity of a model by itself is not the right metric as the calculation depends on the test data too.